# Datagrid for Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1

I want to use a datagrid in one of my modules (Symfony 1.3, Propel ORM). I have spent a while searching the web, but everything I found expects a direct connection to teh db (mySQL) or is otherwise unsuitable.

I found the datagrid plugin (http://symfony.swisscenter.com/datagrid/exemples), but the documentation/examples are in French - and I'm not too keen on learning French just for the sake of using the plugin - besides, if all the users are French speakers, then it will be difficult to get support/help if/when I do hget stuck.

So my questions are:

1. Is anyone aware of a good (PHP) datagrid component that I can use with SF?
2. Is anyone out there (English speaker), using the SF datagrid plugin?

Comment: Why not to use google translate/read code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try a jQuery Plugin. Take a look at [this](http://php-team.blogspot.com/2009/05/10-jquery-datagrid-plugins.html) collection

Comment: looks like exactly what I have been looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think jqGrid is the best among all listed above.
Allows inline editing, adding rows, searching, sorting, column selection, column reordering, resizing, etc out-of-the-box.
Data formats that can be used are datasource, JSON & XML.
Demos at: http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use extJS Grid. ExtJs is having well explained of documentation. We have used this in our sf 1.4 project.

Create a widget that will import extjs Grid

You will have to create rest api for data for the grid. This can be easily achieved by using sfDoctrineRestGeneratorPlugin for doctrine.

I could not find a plugin for propel orm. Rest API can be easily created without a plugin

For Editable ExtJs 4 grid documentation refer http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/example/restful/restful.html

Answer (score 0):

I recently went through the same thing and in the end we went with http://datatables.net/.  You can use it with or without rest and we've found it fits our needs pretty nice.

Answer (score 0):

Going the javascrit way with jquery or Angular will be better.